# Would crosstalk be an effect at < 1 kHz signals up to 2.2A?

Tags: current-measurement, wiring, frequency-response, crosstalk

I'm planning on the use of a current transducer to monitor the current of an induction motor (full load amperage = 2.2A @ 60 Hz).
([Link of current transducer](http://www.lem.com/hq/en/component/option,com_catalog/task,displaymodel/id,90.37.09.000.0/), model: LTS 6-NP)

If I connect the input of the transducer to two parallel 20 AWG wire connections (to allow up to 3A to pass), with a wire length of approximately 10 cm.,
would cross-talk influence the current passing through the wires?

The frequency components of the current being monitored are also of interest, up to 1 kHz.

---

**EDIT:** FYI, I have the input / output wires connected in a twisted-pair manner.

Comment: the undocumented hole looks most interesting, is that a good place to add extra primary windings, or does it have some other purpose?

The data sheet says nothing about the strength of the insulation between the inbuilt primary windings.

Comment: crosstalk is unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: I did test a wire through the hole, doing so just results in the nominal sensitivity of 6A / 0.625V; The only way to achieve higher sensitivities (i.e.: 2A / 0.625V) is to run the current through the side pins. I tried both types of configurations (wire through the hole, wire connected to side pins) while running the induction motor at 60 Hz, 3 phase, and got pretty much identical results. To me that undocumented hole is most likely another means to monitor the current data, albeit without the ability to change the signal sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula

Vinduce = [MU0 * MUr * Area / (2 * PI * Distance)] * dT/dT.

Will you have current spikes, where the 60Hz sinusoid does not define the slewrate?

Comment: I can see some similarities to how the equation relates to how the magnetic field is calculated (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism)) and induced EMF (http://physics.bu.edu/~duffy/PY106/InducedEMF.html, http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/farlaw.html); Is there a reason for dividing by "2 * PI * Distance"?